# Highcharts: High Performance for Multiple charts in a single page

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, highcharts

I am having multiple highcharts in a Single page minimum 10 charts to maximum 25 charts in Single page something like widgets

I used to call the data for highcharts from the server using Ajax Function and I am calling the data from MYSQL Database

There is no any problem regarding the loading of charts but only thing when i load more than 5 charts in a single page, the performance of the highcharts is getting very low, the chart is loading very slowly, I tried some of the methods as suggested in Highcharts website like

Lazy Loading - http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading
Data Grouping - http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping

But none of this technique helps me, still my performance is very slow, example of my coding how i used to call charts

I am having multiple dropdowns, when each time dropdown value is changed the chart will be updated according to the dropdown values

I used to call charts using Ajax functions like this

```
  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "SampleAJAX.aspx",
                    data: "type=CHART1&data="+data1,
                    success: Chart1Success,
                    error: IsError
                });

  $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "SampleAJAX.aspx",
                    data: "type=CHART2&data="+data2,
                    success: Chart2Success,
                    error: IsError
                });
....etc..etc... like wise n number of Ajax functions will be called
```

And after this Ajax Functions i used to call the charts in success functions

```
     function Chart1Success(){
    $('#Chart1').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'pie',
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                            },
                            events: {
                                load: function () {
                                    var msg = "Chart1";
                                    AfterUpdate(msg);
                                },
                            },
                        }
          .................
    });
    }

  function Chart2Success(){
    $('#Chart1').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'column',
                            style: {
                                fontFamily: "Roboto",
                            },
                            events: {
                                load: function () {
                                    var msg = "Chart2";
                                    AfterUpdate(msg);
                                },
                            },
                        }
          .................
    });
    }
  ......etc..etc.... n number of Highcharts continues
```

Sorry for not posting the fiddle as my data are little bit confidential and it is taking my much time for integrating the same thing in fiddle with sample data, if still need i ll try my level best to post

Comment: You need to diagnose where the delays are. Is it in data loading, or in rendering the charts themselves. Use developer tools to look at the loading times.

Comment: The general problem is with your concept, because you call too many ajax, which dicrease page performance, not highcharts.

Comment: Ya My Ajax function is loading much Time , TTFB waiting time is too long for each AJAX

Comment: So well, it is not related with highcharts, but general incorrect software architecture.

Comment: Yes correct Sebastin, Incorrect Software Architecture